# Multiple rows as columns in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this three tables:

student table

```
| _id | name      |
| --- | --------- |
| 1   | Student 1 |
| 2   | Student 2 |
| 3   | Student 3 |
| ... | ...       |
```

subject table

```
| _id | name      |
| --- | --------- |
| 1   | Subject 1 |
| 2   | Subject 2 |
| ... | ...       |
```

relationship between them

```
| student | subject |
| ------- | ------- |
| 1       | 5       |
| 1       | 4       |
| 2       | 7       |
| 3       | 8       |
```

What I want is make a query that looks like this:

```
| student   | subject1  | subject2  |
| --------- | --------- | --------- |
| Student 1 | Subject 5 | Subject 4 |
| Student 2 | Subject 7 | NULL      |
| Student 3 | Subject 8 | NULL      |
```

Each student has 1 or 2 subjects at most.

Tried with

```
SELECT st.name AS student,
       su.name AS subject1,
       su2.name AS subject2
  FROM student AS st
       JOIN
       student_subjects AS ss ON ss.student = st._id
       JOIN
       subject AS su ON ss.subject = su._id
       JOIN
       subject AS su2 ON ss.subject = su2._id
 GROUP BY st._id;
```

but the result is

```
| student   | subject1  | subject2  |
| --------- | --------- | --------- |
| Student 1 | Subject 5 | Subject 5 |
| Student 2 | Subject 7 | Subject 7 |
| Student 3 | Subject 8 | Subject 8 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  If you know there are two subjects:

```
SELECT st.name as student,
       MIN(su.name) as subject1,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(su.name) <> MAX(su.name) THEN MAX(su.name) END) as subject2
FROM student st JOIN
     student_subjects ss
     ON ss.student = st._id JOIN
     subject AS su
     ON ss.subject = su._id
GROUP BY st._id, st.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test a working demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/0c77c/3/0):

```
SELECT S1.Name AS Student,
       MIN(S2.Name) AS Subject1,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(S2.ID) != MAX(S2.ID) THEN MAX(S2.Name) END) AS Subject2
FROM Students S1
     JOIN Relations R ON R.ID_Student = S1.ID
     JOIN Subjects AS S2 ON S2.ID = R.ID_Subject
GROUP BY Student
ORDER BY Student
```

Alternatively, but I find it unnecessarily complex:

```
SELECT
  T1.StudentName AS Student,
  T1.SubjectName AS Subject1,
  (CASE WHEN T1.SubjectName != T2.SubjectName THEN T2.SubjectName END) AS Subject2
FROM 
  (SELECT S1.ID AS StudentID, S1.Name AS StudentName, MIN(S2.Name) AS SubjectName FROM Students S1 JOIN Relations R ON R.ID_Student = S1.ID JOIN Subjects AS S2 ON S2.ID = R.ID_Subject GROUP BY StudentID ORDER BY StudentID) T1
JOIN
  (SELECT S1.ID AS StudentID, S1.Name AS StudentName, MAX(S2.Name) AS SubjectName FROM Students S1 JOIN Relations R ON R.ID_Student = S1.ID JOIN Subjects AS S2 ON S2.ID = R.ID_Subject GROUP BY StudentID ORDER BY StudentID) T2
ON
  T1.StudentID = T2.StudentID
```